# Politics/Medical Science - Unmigrate

Tags: discussion, migration

[Poor Countries](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/what-sustainable-options-do-poorer-non-first-world-countries-have-against-covid) response to Covid-19 has been migrated to Medical Science. The answer that has been posted so far asks for it to be brought back, and this could easily turn into some sort of ping-pong approach, so I thought it would be useful to have a Meta-question about its proper home.

Answer (score 4):

The migration was rejected by medical sciences stack exchange, so I reopened the question.

When answering it, please try to avoid going into medical details.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, my thinking is that the question should come back to politics. If there was a medical science answer for how to deal with Covid-19 that didn't involve mass isolation and ventilating huge numbers of people then the rich western nations would be using it. Ergo, this is not a medical science issue. It's a cost benefit analysis performed by national governments, and is therefore a Politics.SE question.

Brazil's approach is a case in point.